# Does Wordpress support the creation of both an index page and an archives page for a custom post type?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks

I've created a custom post type called "news". I'd like to create a separate index page AND an archives page for this post type. After some research I found that it's recommended to utilize an archive template if you'd like to create an index page for a custom posts type so I created a template called archive-news.php to display all news posts. However, I'd also like a separate archives template for viewing news by month. If my archives page is functioning as my index page, how do I go about creating a separate news archives page?

Comment: You should add some code and show what you have already done. Essentially your idea is correct and the `archive-news.php` is the "index" for your custom post type. What is the difference between an archive and an index page for your news custom post type?

Comment: Essentially the designs are different.